# SSIS File System Task Copy to New Excel File Name w/Date Variable Not Found

Tags: excel, variables, ssis

I have an SSIS File system Task to Copy an Excel template and create one with a date appended.  I get the error saying "the connection is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found."  It's not found because I'm trying to make it!

The preceding error says "Error at File System Task: Failed to lock variable  "c:\Reports\Unregistered_20150915.xlsx" for read access with error 0xC0010001 The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created".

I'm new to this, and all I want to do is run a procedure nightly and put the results in a new Excel file with the date name appended to the end.  My plan was to take a blank worksheet/file and copy it into a new file, then execute the procedure on the server to load into this new file.  As you can see, the variable is filling in the date just fine, so I don't understand how it says the variable cannot be found.

I've used these pages for guidance, but I am taking some of this and some of that, obviously missing something in between:
[Including the Date in a Filename in SSIS using an Expression](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Including%20the%20Date%20in%20a%20Filename%20in%20SSIS%20using%20an%20Expression.aspx)
 and [SSIS: Export a Query Result to a File](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/ssis-export-query-result-to-a-file/) 
Any suggestions, articles, or videos would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: You should now have sufficient reputation to post a screenshot. Double click on your File System task and post a screenshot of what it and the Expressions tab look like. I suspect you have text where you should have a variable reference

Comment: I found the error.  When I set the destination variable, I also had an expression that kept kicking the variable out and using the evaluated result, which is not the name of the variable.  I guess in some way that only a newbie can, I created the variable with the expression and created an additional expression which the program was trying to use concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. When I set the destination variable, I also had an expression that kept kicking the variable out and using the evaluated result, which is not the name of the variable. I guess in some way that only a newbie can, I created the variable with the expression and created an additional expression which the program was trying to use concurrently.